# python __init__ with base classes

Tags: python, class, initialization, init

In python, what is the difference between the two BaseClass initialisation statements below, and which is better? They seem to yield the same result?

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__():
        pass

class MyClass(BaseClass): 
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
```

Comment: to sum up: it's a more powerful way to refer to parent classes in a complex multiple inheritance context, as well as a nicer way to refer to parent constructors, which gets even better in python 3.0

Comment: @zmo - to clarify you mean using the super() method?

Comment: indeed that's what I meant